# javascript transitionEnd not working after some time by setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval

I used setInterval for loop transition, it was normal at first, but after some time, it will be odd

I think it sometimes not call transitionEnd function, but I don't know why
this is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld1b0shj/

My code:
HTML

```
<div id="aaa"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

.box-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.box-trans {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.box-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Javasript:

```
const tt = {
  $boxToast: $('#aaa'),
  active: false,
  go() {
    const obj = this;
    obj.$boxToast.removeClass('box-enter box-trans box-leave');
    obj.active = true;

    function enter() {
      obj.$boxToast.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', boxEnter);
      obj.$boxToast.addClass('box-enter').show().delay(100).queue(function() {
        obj.$boxToast.addClass('box-trans').dequeue();

        setTimeout(function() {
          obj.$boxToast.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', boxLeave);
          obj.$boxToast.addClass('box-leave');
        }, 1000)
      });
    }

    function boxEnter() {
      obj.$boxToast.removeClass('box-enter');
      obj.$boxToast.off('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', boxEnter);
    }

    function boxLeave() {
      obj.$boxToast.removeClass('box-leave box-trans');
      obj.$boxToast.hide();
      obj.active = false;
      obj.$boxToast.off('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', boxLeave);
    }
    enter();
  }
}

setInterval(function(){
  tt.go();
}, 5000)
```

Thanks every one

Edit:

This is odd gif url
https://upload.cc/i1/2019/10/23/mj6gbu.gif

And the dom's variation
https://upload.cc/i1/2019/10/23/TNzj0o.gif

Comment: `but after some time, it will be odd` ... what time? what is odd? Do you think we have time to watch your flashing blue box for several hours and then notice something odd?

Comment: If your `interval` value is less than `1100 ml` it might cause the effect start before the previous effect end. Because you have `delay` 100 ml and `setTimeout` for 1000 ml in your effect logic. To make sure the previous effect ended, set your interval value larger than `1100 ml`

Comment: @Bravo sorry, i want to post some image but i can't do it, because my point is low, 
i know it's vague, I upload odd gif  like this
https://upload.cc/i1/2019/10/23/mj6gbu.gif, 
probably wait 5 minutes will be that,
sorry I rarely ask questions, I will improve next time,
Thank you common for it

Comment: @ChickenSoups but my interval is _5000ml_, it still has the question